# finding function such that $f(2x) = f(x) + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Q1. How to find a [function $f(x)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%282x%29=f%28x%29%2b1&dataset=) satisfying the recurrence relation
>   $$f(2x) = f(x) + 1$$
>
> Q2. Also how to prove that the closed form for the recurrence relation
>   $$f(n) = f \left( \left \lfloor \frac n 2  \right \rfloor \right ) + 1$$
>   with $f(0) = 0$ is given by $f(n) = \lfloor \log_2 (n)\rfloor + 1$.

Comment: what is equal  $f(1)$? or $f(0)$?

Comment: So $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=0$, correct?

Comment: @datodatuashvili assume $f(1) = 0$

Comment: "How do I show that a function ..."  I guess you're asking "How do I *find* a function ..."?

Comment: @John sorry ...yes to that. After I put that function in W|A, i get the result but I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1** Since the recurrence relation only tells you what $f$ is at even integers, you are free to define it at the odd integers. Then, you can prove that

$$f(2^k(2m+1))=f(2m+1)+k \,,$$

where $f$ is defined any way you want on the odd integers.

A simple choice is to define $f(2m+1)=0$ for all $m$, and then the above formula yields $f(n)=$the power of $2$ in $n$.

**Q2**  Let $k:=  \lfloor \log_2 (n)\rfloor $. Then $2^k \leq n < 2^{k+1}$.

Since

$$2^{k-1} \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor < 2^k$$

Your result becomes an easy induction by $k$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, would $y=log_2x$ work?
After all, $log_2(2x)=log_2x+1$ is a true statement?
Just guessing here...

Comment: that guessing I want to avoid :(

Comment: But my answer works? It satisfies the statement

Comment: This only attempts to answer half of the post, and it doesn't even answer the first half very confidently... would make a better comment.

Comment: @rschwieb I know, I was just trying. It works, but I have no proof of other functions that work other than changing the base of the logarithm. It was pure trial...